# "Server Error" on localhost LAMP server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, lamp

I'm not too experienced with server issues and stuff like that. I have a LAMP server setup on Ubuntu 12.04 for local PHP and web development.

It was working fine just a little bit ago, then one time I refreshed and got this, it's been doing it ever since.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcXB8.png

I've tried restarting Apache using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It restarts fine, and then when I refresh on chromium, I get the same thing. Could this be an error with Chromium and not my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index.php` of `/ImgUP/` seems to be reporting an error that makes it give a `500` error. It's an issue with the code of said file, not chrome. Hope this helps and DFTBA. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, I can't believe I didn't see that. I was require_once'ing a mysql_connect script. Didn't realize I had typed the filepath to it wrong, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

As jason said, there is something probably wrong with the code for the site. Check the default error log in /var/log/apache2/error.log, and if there is a specific error log file for your site, check that one too.

If you need help reading the log files, update your question with the relevant lines.